# Enumerate clarification

Tags: python, enumerate

This is the code that I was given:

```
cast = ["Barney Stinson", "Robin Scherbatsky", "Ted Mosby", "Lily Aldrin", "Marshall Eriksen"]
heights = [72, 68, 72, 66, 76]

print(cast)
```

This is the desired output:

```
['Barney Stinson 72', 'Robin Scherbatsky 68', 'Ted Mosby 72', 'Lily Aldrin 66', 'Marshall Eriksen 76']
```

This is the solution:

```
cast = ["Barney Stinson", "Robin Scherbatsky", "Ted Mosby", "Lily Aldrin", "Marshall Eriksen"]
heights = [72, 68, 72, 66, 76]

for i, character in enumerate(cast):
    cast[i] = character + " " + str(heights[i])

print(cast)
```

This is the question for this piece of code:

```
for i, character in enumerate(cast):
    cast[i] = character + " " + str(heights[i])
```

Why are the putting `cast[i]` and `heights[i]` and not only cast/heights?
If it is a enumerate function is it supposed to number all names?

example:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
    print(i, letter)
```

This code would output:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
```

Comment: You should use zip(), that gives exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the characters of `cast` while you're iterating over it while also taking the position of the same character in the heights list.

You cannot use `height` because that's not a valid variable name in that loop and heights is the entire list; go ahead and try using it, it won't give you the desired output

If you did the following, then the cast list wouldn't change after the loop

```
character += " " + str(heights[i])
```

Note: `zip(cast, height)` will give you very similar output

For example,

```
print([c + " " + h in zip(cast, heights)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question:

> Why are the putting cast[i] and heights[i] and not only cast/heights? If it is a enumerate function is it supposed to number all names?

When you create a `for loop` using `enumerate()`, like this:

```
for counter, value in enumerate(some_list):
```

The first variable `counter` is equal to the index of the list, while `value` is equal to the element present in the list at that index.

[Source](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)